# Amazon MWS API using PHP shows no Result

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have been using amazon mws API for developing a project to find Lowest Priced offers, It works fine with action ListMatchingProducts and GetMatchingProduct but when it comes to GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN, it shows no result in XML output

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

**My PHP File Here:**

```css
<?php
$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = ''; 
$param['Action']           = 'GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN';
$param['SellerId']         = ''; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256';  
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$param['Version']          = '2011-10-01'; 
$param['MarketplaceId']    = 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'; 
$param['ItemCondition']    = 'used';
$param['ASIN']      = '0439139600';
$secret = '';
$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

 $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
 $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
 $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'GET' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Products/2011-10-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header('Content-type:text/xml');
echo $response;
```

I can't put AWSAccessKeyID, Secret and SellerID here...

Comment: I don't think you are using Amazon MWS PHP SDK

Comment: yes, sorry, changed that, I have not used SDK, but it's simple cURL request to get the result, for everything else it works perfect, but for GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN, it doesnt shows any result.

Comment: It's really easy to use PHP SDK and will save your lot time

Comment: actually I found a solution, but problem with it is that, it requires POST request and using POST request signature becomes invalid

Comment: can you have any easy example of SDK, I think SDK is more complicated

Comment: Marmik Bhai if you want to use SDK then i can help you with any API calls as i am using pricechange,reporting,fbainbound/outbound, feeds api

Comment: just wanted to learn how to make a simple call in POST request

Comment: Using SDK I am getting this error: Caught Exception: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate Response Status Code: Error Code: Error Type: HTTP Request ID: XML: ResponseHeaderMetadata:

Comment: Hi Marmik again i need to see our code to help you. or give me your email address and i can send you some code which might help you

Comment: marmikbhatt@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93574/discussion-between-marmik-bhatt-and-keyur).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is, that you use GET instead of POST.
This version of your code works:

```
$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = ''; 
$param['Action']           = 'GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN';
$param['MarketplaceId']    = 'A1PA6795UKMFR9';
$param['SellerId']         = ''; 
$param['ASIN']             = 'B002BYQIWM'; 
$param['ItemCondition']    = 'New'; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256';  
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
$param['Version']          = '2011-10-01'; 
$secret = '';
$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {
                    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
                        $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
                        $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'POST' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.de' . "\n";
$sign .= '/Products/2011-10-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$s64 = base64_encode($signature);

$signature = urlencode($s64);
$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.de/Products/2011-10-01";
$arr .= "&Signature=" . $signature;

$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept:'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

I have used `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to debug the response from server. Your code did not produced any http body to output, but this http header `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed`. Changing to POST solved your problem.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, thanks for your answer, but I have tried using POST method, with POST method I get this error: Sender SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

Comment: Please try my code. It is working. Signature is valid and the XML with the competitor offers is returned.